# Let f be monotone on the interval [a,b]. Given that f has anti-derivatives on [a,b], prove that f is continuous on [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be monotone on the interval $[a,b]$. Given that $f$ has anti derivatives on $[a,b]$, prove that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

Comment: This is equivalent to showing thet $f([a,b])$ is connected, you could try Darboux's theorem.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: The function can only fail to be continuous if there is a gap in the range. Since $f=F'$ and $f$ is monotone it cannot have a gap.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay, I get it. The idea is to show that Darboux and monotone implies continuous.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: That's it. I was putting as much effort into the solution as the OP was :-).

Answer (score 0):

WLOG assume $f$ is nondecreasing. If $f$ is not continuous at some $c\in [a,b],$ then one of the following must hold: i) $\lim_{x\to c^+} f(x) > f(c)$ ii) $\lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) < f(c).$

Suppose i) holds. Then by the MVT, for small $h>0$ we have

$$\frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}{h} = F'(c_h) = f(c_h),\,\,\text { for some } c_h\in (c, c+h).$$

As $h\to 0^+,$ $c_h\to 0^+,$ hence $f(c_h)$ approaches a limit greater than $f(c).$ That violates $F'(c) = f(c),$ contradiction